# Delete lines from tdbmemo

Tags: c++builder

I want to delete line(s) from my TDBMemo field if it contains a specific string.

How can I go about it in C++ Builder XE version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. it how i do it for a normal memo

```
UnicodeString KeyPhrase = "the str your looking for";
for (int i = 0; i < DBMemo1->Lines->Count ; i++)
{
UnicodeString LineToCheck = DBMemo1->Lines->Strings[i];
if( LineToCheck.Pos( KeyPhrase ) )
        {
    DBMemo1->Lines->Delete(i);
            }
}
```

Comment: I tried this. But then when reading from my memo field ( data which is pulled from the tables) it picks up :2 lines as a single line: Line1\nLine2. This makes the output wrong. Anyway I can specify a delimiter of \n ???

Comment: Worked. I used a DBMemo->Lines->Delimiter = '\n' and then it seems to split the lines easily and delete specific line :) Thank you!